# UiRouter - stateparames is null

Tags: angularjs

In controller i get `$stateParams.foo` is undefined

```
MoviesApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: '/Partial/home.html'
        })
        .state('movieDetails', {
            url: '/allPlaces',
            views: {
                '': {
                  templateUrl: '/Partial/movieDetails.html',
                  controller: 'movieDetailsCtrl'
                }
           }
     });
});

   /*.state('home', {
        url: '/:foo?bar',
        views: {
            '': {
               templateUrl: 'tpl.home.html',
               controller: 'MainRootCtrl'

    },*/

MoviesApp.controller('movieDetailsCtrl', function($scope, $state,$stateParams) {
      //..
      var foo = $stateParams.foo; //getting fooVal
      var bar = $stateParams.bar; //getting barVal
      //..
      $scope.state = $state.current
      $scope.params = $stateParams; 
})
```

Comment: Try MoviesApp.controller('movieDetailsCtrl', ['$scope', '$state','$stateParams'], function($scope, $state, $stateParams)

Answer (score 0):

```
MoviesApp.controller('movieDetailsCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', '$stateParams'], function($scope, $state, $stateParams) { 
  var foo = $stateParams.foo;
  var bar = $stateParams.bar;
  $scope.state = $state.current
  $scope.params = $stateParams; 
})
```

Try this, you probably forgot to inject a $stateParams to controller

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up your state like this:

```
.state('home', { 
  url: '/:foo/:bar', 
  views: { 
    '': {templateUrl: 'tpl.home.html', controller: 'MainRootCtrl'}
  }
}
```

And then go to that state for example by using: ng-sref

```
<a ui-sref='home({foo: value, bar: value})'>klick me</a>
```